# Is there a way to temporary save user input or responses to a list of questions in your xamarin app before posting it to the web api?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using MVVM design pattern, I have a ViewModelBase that has a static variable to hold a list of responses to a survey, every other viewModel inherits from the viewModelbase, I add a response to the list, but when i navigate to a different page with a different question, the static variable (list of responses to the survey) it resets and does not save the response ?, does any one have any suggestions. Thank you.

For example i have : ViewModelBase

```
  public class ViewModelBase : ExtendedBindableObject
  {
     private static ListOfResponses _Responses;
     public ListOfResponses Responses{
      get { return _Responses;}
      set{ _Responses = value;    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Responses);} 
     }
     public ViewModelBase(){ _Responses = new ListOfResponses();}
  }
```

for the model :

```
public class ListOfResponses {
  public List<Response> ResponseList {get;set;}
  public int surveyParticipant{get;set;}
}
```

for the View model adding to the list of responses:

```
public class AddResponses{
    private Response _Response;
    public Response Response{
    get{return _Response;}
    set{
     if(_Response== value) {return;}
       _Response= value;
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => Response);
    }
 }


   public ICommand addResponse{get;set;}

   public class AddResponses(Response _Response){ addResponse = new Command(AddToList);  this._Response = _Response;}

   public async void AddToList(){await performAddToList();}

   private async Task performAddToList(){
     if(Response != null){
        _Responses.Add(Response);
       await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<NextQuestionViewModel>();
     }
   }
}
```

Second Approach:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
  public class ViewModelBase : ExtendedBindableObject
  {
     private static ListOfResponses _Responses = new ListOfResponses();
     public List<Response> ListResponse = new List<Response>();
     public ListOfResponses Responses{
      get { return _Responses;}
      set{ _Responses.ResponseList  = ListResponse ;    RaisePropertyChanged(() => Responses);} 
     }
     public ViewModelBase(){ }
  }
```

and in the other view model base :

```
    public class AddResponses{
        private Response _Response;
        public Response Response{
        get{return _Response;}
        set{
        if(_Response== value) {return;}
           _Response= value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => Response);
    }
 }


   public ICommand addResponse{get;set;}

   public class AddResponses(Response _Response){ addResponse = new Command(AddToList);  this._Response = _Response;}

   public async void AddToList(){await performAddToList();}

   private async Task performAddToList(){
     if(Response != null){
        ListResponse .Add(Response);
       await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<NextQuestionViewModel>();
     }
   }
}
```

I also tried that but it does not work.

Comment: we can't debug code we can't see

Comment: thanks for your reply @Jason, I just add code.

Comment: ViewModelBase initializes _Responses in it's constructor.  So every new VM instance you create will clear out any previous responses you saved.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Jason, i also tried a second approach creating the object in the view model base but not in the constructor. what do u suggest ?. thanks

Comment: the simplest thing would be to check if _Responses is null before initializing it

Comment: okay i see what you mean, so in any view model i am that needs to add to the list, i do the check and then add ? thank you @Jason

Comment: no, in the ViewModelBase constructor.  If it's not null then don't initialize it.

Comment: okay thank you @Jason

Comment: @LISA Hi , does it be solved now ?

Comment: It still does not work , @JuniorJiang-MSFT

Comment: I did some more research and using static variables they say is against OOP. @Jason

Comment: @LISA Okey , if can't saving the data when navigating , you can have a try with scrollview to put all question view in One Controller (Scrollview to achieve page switching) . Then not need to consider storaging data of list .

Comment: As @Jason mentioned, either check _Responses if it is already instantiated or even better use singleton instances for classes you need.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I did think of that, but the problem is that, i have 3 different types of format a question can take and the responses to the question would be a different type( string, date, etc), i implemented those types of separate pages and view model depending on the format.

Comment: @zpouip thanks you, i would look into that.

Comment: @LISA Okey , got it . The logic is special, if have a sample project will know more about it .